# Read email attachment

Tags: php

I have emails piped to a PHP script, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php

// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd))
{
        $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);


mail('test@test.com','From TEST','"' . $email . '"');

?>
```

This essentially sends me the entirety of the email.

I can't seem to find anything that doesn't rely on existing frameworks to read attachments.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting just the attachment data? The attachment will always be a CSV file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save email attachment from piped email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964430/save-email-attachment-from-piped-email)

Comment: Having written the linked answer, and then yet more code to parse MIME multipart data, please take this advice: unless you can recite RFCs by heart you should find a class to do this for you and save yourself a *lot* of stress. [This one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html) is ugly as sin, but it works.